# subprocess to call sh script in flask app filed to run

Tags: flask

i am new in flask , 
i have app that call to subprocess,
the flask is install in virtual environment on ubuntu (can i install flask without virtual environment?)
this my app code, 
once i call the subprocess  i get flask error that the "/bin/sh: 1: /home/me/oneview-ansible/esxi.sh: **not found**" 
i have try the full  path to the sh file but unable to run it , 
attached my app code,

thanks for the help

```
@app.route('/vare', methods=["POST"])
def vare():
    json_obj = request.form.to_dict()
    with open('/home/me/oneview-ansible/vare.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(js.dumps(json_obj))
    subprocess.call(['/home/me/oneview-ansible/esxi.sh'], shell=True)
    return {"status": "ok"
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

add "sh" and the ./script name,
thanks!